# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS missing sleep option

Tags: 18.04, suspend, gnome-shell

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and realized that when I click the poweroff button (most upper right) there is no option for sleep/suspend? I only have restart and poweroff (and cancal) options. In 16.04 that I have in my laptop I have also suspend option.